# how can i override Drupal 7 page.tpl.php but not sub pages?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, overriding

OK so im using the profile2 module, and i want to override the page.tpl.php for the URL **http://website.com/profile-main**

I have created **page--profile_main.tpl.php** and this works perfect, however i dont want the changes to also affect pages which follow that page, for example **http://website.com/profile-main/2456** or **/profile-main/another/page**

is this possible? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first questions is, how do you want to do it? Do you want to do it a page/path or a node? If you want to override it for all the nodes of certain types or want to override for a path, I would suggest you to use panels pages instead. Its very flexible and you can achieve what you want!

Comment: Well im doing it for a path (profile-main). This is the path for the profile2 module, so when a user visits '/profile-main' they see their own profile, '/profile-main/uid' would then display the profile of the user with the uid in the url.. So i want to edit the path for only the logged in user so when they visit '/profile-main' they only see the changes on their own profile. I tried using panels but it gives me an error saying the path is already in use and i cant override it. I think panels and profile2 are not compatible

Comment: Well, you should do it with the original path 'user/<uid>'. Panels gives you great flexibility to show the 'variant' of the page based on criteria like user role, context and others. So, learn the panels, its a quick & manageable solution!

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by using the original path 'user/uid'.. That path is used by Drupal to display the Main user profile, the Profile2 module uses a different path because the profile2 profile for each user is separate to their main profile which is held at 'user/uid'. The path for the profile2 profile is 'profile-main/uid' and a user can access their own profile by simply going to '/profile-main', but as mentioned this path cant be modified in panels, it wont let me

Comment: By user/<uid>, I meant, you can override the appearance of that page using panel pages. When you install panels, you get a menu item 'Pages' under 'structure' (for 7.x). This is where you can override its appearance. You can use views, blocks etc. to populate the page. Have a look at http://bizbo.joshics.in/user/1
On this page, the left side is panel, while the right sidebar has blocks.